# Error to render Inline PDF with CGI in Python 3.7

Tags: apache, cgi, python-3.7

When script is executed with python CGI PDF is feching well. But if i import script in another module unable to fetch pdf.

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

import os,io,html,sys
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
data  = 'Create a new PDF with Reportlab Swamy® RedteK 4104      DE*    ≤     0.4       &#8804; 1.5     *'

packet = io.BytesIO()
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
strdata = data.encode('utf-8','xmlcharrefreplace')
cat = str(html.unescape(strdata.decode()))
can.drawString(10, 500, cat)
can.showPage()
can.save()
packet.seek(0) 

print('Content-type: application/pdf')
print('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="out.pdf"')

print('\n\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.__stdout__.buffer.write(packet.getvalue())
```

PDF fetched when module when script is initiated directly.
[image]

Error when import in another module
Error in apache errorlogs: malformed header from script. Bad header=%PDF-1.3:

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

A guess from a non-python guy here:

```
print('Content-type: application/pdf')
print('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="out.pdf"')

print('\n\n')
```

looks suspicious: A linebreak is required after each HTTP-header:

```
print('Content-type: application/pdf')
print('\n')
print('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="out.pdf"')

print('\n\n')
```

As you say you see "malformed header from script" in the logs: Monitor them. I assume that the version without an extra linebreak just has the `Content-Type` header with a really weird content type:

```
Content-type: application/pdfContent-Disposition: inline; filename="out.pdf"
```

while the browser (and server) could (and should) make use of

```
Content-type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="out.pdf"
```